# Building a multilabel classifier for text

Tags: classification

I am given a number of short texts (very likely to be shorter than 25 words). The specificity of the short texts is that it can (logically) belong to one or multiple categories. For example:

```
find the closest starbucks and then remind me to call bob
```

The short text can be attributed two labels: NAVIGATION and PHONE. I have a large number of short texts like this and most of them have 2 parts, very rarely 3 parts. The word ``and'' not always is the clear indicator of part separation!

My question: How can I approach such classification problem? What techniques/ideas are worth exploring?

I am currently thinking about two approaches:

1. Try multilabel classifier such as MPBoost;
2. Perform some pre-segmentation using CRF and then classify each segment using a standard multiclass classifier.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your correction correctly, I would recommend to extract some features from your short texts and then use a binary classifier to classify them as navigation or phone, after learning.

You can follow the steps describe in this tutorial (it is made for Python but I believe the same steps can be applied in another language): http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the latter approach is likely to give better results, because the model doesn't have to disambiguate the segments' words' contribution to the multiple labels. However, that comes at the cost of requiring you to label the individual segments; if that's quite costly, the first approach may be "good enough."